# Splitting text across multiple TextViews/Fragments using ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview, android-viewpager

I'm trying to split some text across multiple Fragments loaded into a ViewPager using the Android compatibility library. The idea is to have something akin to the Kindle app, where you are swiping across multiple pages of text.

Initially, my source of text is a string defined in strings.xml and I am using an algorithm to determine the height of the device screen, and then split this string accordingly into a number of items for the ViewPager. As you can't get the height of a TextView ahead of time, I am just using a percentage value to determine what to set the maximum size of the TextView to on each page (this seems a bit ugly).

Does this seem like a reasonable approach, or am I going about this all the wrong way?

Comment: I write an example but I didn't like it. I also wonder how to implement a better way.

Comment: First off I would not use strings.xml for a large text. I would import a .txt file or something of the sort instead. Once that loads into the fragment you should be able to create an `if-statement` to move text to another page if the current page is filled.

Answer (score 1):

> As you can't get the height of a TextView ahead of time

Well, that depends on what you mean by "ahead of time" (time == text processing?).

- You can `measure()` your `ViewPager`/`TextView` once and use its `getMeasuredHeight()/getMeasuredWidth()` in your calculations
- You can wait for `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.onGlobalLayout()` and use the "standard" layout measurements for the very same thing
- (Not recommended) you can use ("screen height" - "decorations height") / "text height (font + spacing)" to know how many text lines will fit in your TextView
- Etc. etc.