# Get measure height of a TextView without add to the view hierarchy

Tags: android

I get following **requirement**.

1. I need to build a tree with leaves placed left and right, from the screen top to the bottom. I can not put the leaves in a ListView because tow leaves will be in same offset.
2. I don't know the height of the items.
3. I need to pre-calculate the height of dynamic content, such as strings with different lengths.

**QUESTION:**

How can i pre-calculate the height of a sting which will be put in a TextView widget described as follows:

```
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/note_content"
    android:layout_width="40sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="5" />
```

[image]

Comment: You problem is better handled after the view has been drawn on screen. Use `ViewTreeObserver` to make changes to `TextView` placement.

Comment: I am trying to find a way before i draw the view to the screen, will  measure() work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345384/splitting-text-across-multiple-textviews-fragments-using-viewpager/17536992#17536992

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create textView, set LayoutParams, set text, call it's measure method and read measured values. BTW you can measure text, not textView (see [StaticLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/StaticLayout.html)).

I think you better create your custom layout where you can implement all your "leaves measument" algorithms. [Check this lesson.](http://www.parleys.com/play/514892280364bc17fc56c0e2/chapter0/about) Custom layout is very easy )

Answer (score 0):

Use this for calculate height and width your textview

```
    textView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                 h=textView.getHeight();
                 w=textView.getWidth();
        textView.getViewTreeObserver()
                            .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
    }
```

But in xml do not assign textview as a wrap content. Because it will give you value 0.

Comment: this event will triggered after i put the TextView to the view hierarchy. I need to know the height of TextView and i can layout it in my customized view group.